# How to update foreignkey field manually in UpdateView post method?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to manually change a foreign key field (Supplier) of a model (Expenditure). I override the `UpdateView` post method of Expenditure and handle forms for other models in this method too. A new `SupplierForm` is also rendered in this view and I am tracking if this form is changed via `has_changed()` method of the form. If this form has changed, what I ask is overriding the `related_supplier` field of `ExpenditureForm` and picking newly created `Supplier` by this statement:

```
if supplier_form_changed:
  new_supplier = related_supplier_form.save(commit=False)
  new_supplier.save()
  ....
  # This statement seems to have no effect
  self.object.related_supplier = new_supplier
```

I override the post method with `super()`, so even though I explicitly state `save()` method for all related forms, however I don't call the save method of main model (Expenditure) since it is already handled after `super()`. This is what start and end of my method looks like;

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = request.POST
    related_receipt_form = self.receipt_form_class(context, request.FILES)
    related_supplier_form = self.supplier_form_class(context, request.FILES)
    self.object = self.get_object()
    related_receipt = self.object.receipt
    related_supplier_form = self.supplier_form_class(context)
    expenditure_form = self.form_class(context)
    inlines = self.construct_inlines()
    ....
    return super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You may find the full code of my entire view here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZtCfMHSBZN/

So my problem is `self.object.related_supplier = new_supplier` statement does not have any effect. After the update, old `related_supplier` object is still there, new one is saved but not attached to the updated `Expenditure`. Strange thing is I am doing a similar thing in the same view (also in CreateView) with receipt and no problem whatsoever.

I debugged the code via PyCharm, before the execution of `super()`, I can confirm that self.object.related_supplier is the newly created one, but when the `super()` executed, it returns back to the original supplier object.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the form valid method to add things manually, an example shown below

```
   def form_valid(self, form):
        related_supplier_form.instance.related_supplier = new_supplier
        valid_data = super(UpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
        return valid_data
```

Comment: I know it is not a good practice but I put all my business logic in this method, and would prefer to keep things here. How would I still use my custom validations written in `post()`, and change the behavior of `form_valid()` depending on these?